# Customizable hamburger menu icons (Size)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm using Template 10, and wanted to put icones made by me on the hamburguer menu, but I'm having a problem in size. I've tried it in many ways, and sometimes the icon gets too big and at other times too small, I can not find the ideal size. What is the recommended size for the icon?

Comment: Could you please detail in which situation looks big and in which situation looks small? And relative code please.

Comment: My code: `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BitmapIcon Width="48"
                              Height="48"
                              UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="ABC" />
                </StackPanel>`